# jQuery "Does not have attribute" selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can find a div that has an attribute like so:

```
$('.funding-plan-container[data-timestamp]')
```

But if I try to find a div that does not have that attribute, I get an error - my code is:

```
$('.funding-plan-container[!data-timestamp]')
```

Is there a "does not have attribute" selector in jQuery?

For reference, the use case here is that any div that does not have a timestamp attribute was not added dynamically, and hence is useful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 248, accepted):

Use the [`:not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) selector.

```
$('.funding-plan-container:not([data-timestamp])')
```

---

This, by the way, is a valid [*Selectors API*](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-api/) selector, so it isn't specific to jQuery. It'll work with `querySelectorAll()` and in your CSS *(given [browser support](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel3))*.

Comment: Other way to write it `$('.funding-plan-container').not('[data-timestamp]')

Answer (score 44):

You can filter the selector by using **[.not()](http://api.jquery.com/not/)** or **[:not()](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/)** selector.

```
$('.funding-plan-container:not([data-timestamp])').
```

OR

```
$('.funding-plan-container').not('[data-timestamp]')
```

Answer (score 9):

Try it with the `:not()` pseudo-class selector: http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/

```
$('.funding-plan-container:not([data-timestamp])')
```