# 'Does not have class' selector in jQuery. Select an element by particular class name which holds multiple classes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to select an element by a particular class name (the element holds multiple classes). I have referenced [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12731428/jquery-does-not-have-attribute-selector) but did not work for me.

```
<i class="fas fa-star fa-lg clicked"></i>
<i class="fas fa-star fa-lg"></i>
<i class="fas fa-star fa-lg"></i>
```

`clicked` is a custom class with `color:red` inside.

**Javascript code**:

```
$("i").click(()=> {
    changeColor();
})

const changeColor = () => {
    if (!$(this).hasClass('clicked')) {
        console.log('not clicked class')
    }
}
```

or

```
const changeColor = () => {
   if ($("i:not(.clicked)")){
     console.log("no clicked class")
   }
}
```

Both implementations do not work. If you know why, please let me know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not capturing the `this` reference correctly, arrow notation can't use the implicit `this` reference, avoid using it with `jQuery`:

> An arrow function expression has a shorter syntax than a function expression and does not have its own `this`, `arguments`, `super`, or `new.target`. These function expressions are best suited for non-method functions, and they cannot be used as constructors.

I have reworked your code so it can work as you expect:

```js
$("i").click(function()
{
    changeColor($(this));
});

const changeColor = (obj) =>
{
    if (!obj.hasClass('clicked'))
        console.log('not clicked class');
}
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}

.clicked {
   color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<i class="fas fa-star fa-lg clicked">Button 1</i>
<i class="fas fa-star fa-lg">Button 2</i>
<i class="fas fa-star fa-lg">Button 3</i>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. So, we cannot properly capture $(this) inside nested arrow functions? I have been reading some articles on 'non-method functions' but not sure if I fully understood. In short, I should not use arrow function if I am referencing any element outside the lexical scope of its arrow function. Correct?

Comment: There is no need of nesting, you can't capture `$(this)` as the context where the click event occurs inside an arrow function. You can read more here: [Arrow  Functions](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/when-and-why-you-should-use-es6-arrow-functions-and-when-you-shouldnt-3d851d7f0b26) and [Lexical Scope](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2014/10/20/javascript-scope-closures/). Also, consider accepting the answer as correct if it helps you.

Comment: Thanks, you really helped me. I will study when to use arrow functions and when NOT to use arrow functions.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of mentioned `this` you can use `event.currentTarget` instead:

```js
$("i").click(function(event)
{
    changeColor($(event.currentTarget));
});

const changeColor = ($element) =>
{
    if (!$element.hasClass('clicked'))
        console.log('not clicked class');
}
```

```css
.clicked {
   color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<i class="fas fa-star fa-lg clicked">Button 1</i>

<i class="fas fa-star fa-lg">Button 2</i>

<i class="fas fa-star fa-lg">Button 3</i>
```

Using `this` in the code can be confusing because you need to have good knowledge how it works. Many people tend to not use it because of that.

Bear in mind that I renamed the `obj` to `$element`. I strongly recommend to use `$` prefix to show that this variable holds a jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using `element.is('.clicked')`? You can try more than one combination with [is](http://api.jquery.com/is/)