# Find elements with no attributes at all

Tags: jquery

It's well documented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12731428/jquery-does-not-have-attribute-selector/12731453) how to find an element that is missing a particular attribute. But how can I find a `<span>` (using jQuery) with no attributes at all?

For example, I want a selector that finds this:

```
<span>Some stuff here</span>
```

...but ignores this:

```
<span id='foo'>Some stuff here</span>
```

...and ignores this:

```
<span class='FooCls'>Some stuff here</span>
```

etc...etc...

How is it done?

Comment: @LeandroBardelli I approve of that suggestion :)

Comment: @freedomn-m glorious!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33254207/jquery-selector-for-an-element-without-any-attribute/69947163#69947163

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
const noAttributeElements = $("span").filter(function(){ 
    return this.attributes.length === 0; 
});
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using Filter. Example:

```js
$(function() {
  var mySpans = $("span").filter(function(index) {
    return $(this)[0].attributes.length == 0
  });
  console.log(mySpans.length);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span>Some stuff here</span>
<span id='foo'>Some stuff here</span>
<span class='FooCls'>Some stuff here</span>
```

Comment: I don't see any benefit in using `$(this)[0]` - you've wrapped `this` in a new jQuery wrapper, only to pull it back out again. Just use `this` directly.

Comment: @RichardDeeming no benifit there yet using `*` selector is not advised.

Comment: Agreed. I read the title ("Find *elements* with...") rather than the question ("Find a `span` with...").